# How to input data from keyboard with List<String> in C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, input, keyboard

I need to write a console application which allows users input list of string as Full Name (First Name and Last Name). After that, write SortName(string[] arr) method to implement following requirements:

- You need to sort their Last Name in alphabet.
- If Full Name has only one word, it will be treated as Last Name

Example Input:

> Tony Stark, Steve Rogers, Bruce Banner, Thor, Natasha Romanoff, Clint Barton, James Rhodes, Scott
>   Lang, Doctor Strange, Carol Danvers, Peter Parker
>   Output: Bruce Banner, Clint Barton, Carol Danvers, Scott Lang, Peter Parker, James Rhodes, Steve Rogers,
>   Natasha Romanoff, Tony Stark, Doctor Strange, Thor

So how can I do this?

Comment: You cannot post your homework assignment and hope someone will build it for you. However if you already tried something and have specific issues, then we are glad to help. As long as you show your code and explain those issues

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Oh I'm sorry!!! Actually I don't know how to input data like string name from keyboard with List<>. I think posting all content will easy to understand for everyone. So thank you

Comment: You can use Console.ReadLine to get one line from the keyboard, as string. Then you need to store it in the list yourself

Comment: Can you show me an example code about this? I am quite unclearly how to do

Answer (score 0):

As it is a homework assignment, I will not show real code. Instead I will try and explain what you should do. Don't try and tackle this in one go (when everyrhing is new), just take small steps.

### Iteration 1

Use `Console.ReadLine()` to read in one string into a string variable. Then use `Console.WriteLine()` to print it, maybe with some additional text like `"you entered: "`

### Iteration 2

Now try and fill a `List<string>`. First create one, then in a loop ask for names and add them to the list. You can start with a simple for-loop to ask for exactly 5 names.

### Iteration 3

Change this for-loop to a different type of loop so you can ask for any number of names. Keep going until the user enters a blank name (=just hit enter when asked for a name).

### Iteration 4

Loop over the list to print out the names. They will come out in the order you entered - sorting will come next.

### Iteration 5

Sort the list in alphabetical order and print it. This will be sorted on first name, not last name, for now.

### Iteration 6

You will need to define your own sorting comparison. When you compare two names, you will need to split each name on the space and take (and compare) just the last part.